# How to Open .rd file extension in Java

Tags: java, file, rd

Can anyone help me in figuring out how to retreive data from  .rd extension files in java. I want to copy data from .rd extension file into a word document file. I am new to java and hence unable to sort out the problem.

Thanks in Advance
Sai

Answer (score 0):

See these documents :

1. Guidelines for Rd files : http://developer.r-project.org/Rds.html
2. Parsing Rd File : http://developer.r-project.org/parseRd.pdf

Once you are able to read the file by previous methods, you can convert into word document by using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/index.html).

Hope This Helps!